# ASP.NET Core High CPU Usage in ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, http, threadpool

The Visual Studio performance profiler shows a high amount of CPU usage in the ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch method for an ASP.NET Core application. The CPU usage seems to increase with the number of incoming HTTP requests. I'm concerned this could be thread pool starvation.

I've tried setting ThreadPool.SetMinThreads, fixing blocking calls on async tasks, and taking long running threads off of the thread pool. But I still see the same CPU usage in that method. Is this a known issue, or is there something else I need to try?

Comment: Is the application doing any heavy CPU-bound processing?